# Flash AS3, drawing letter while moving between different points on this letter

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I would like to draw letter while moving between points on this letter
I tried lineTo between two points and it works right with straight lines but it fails with curves "like O for example"
Is there other technique that can be helpful? 
I tried to use curveTo but I couldn't, any suggestions? any ready online code for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the idea to have the letter itself drawn as dimmed in the stage, divided the letter itself to buttons and changed the button color while on mouse over, I hope this will be helpful.